# How do I get next property to not show in overflow

Tags: html, css

I made this overflow hanger so that it would show some of the skills that I have. The only problem now is that the next property is showing up on it. I am looking for a way for the information to always be under the overflow I created.

```css
body{
    background-color: #FFF ;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#contact-button{
    border-radius: .1rem;
    color: #FF5733  ;
    border:  solid .1rem;
    background: #f8f9fa;
    padding: .2rem;
    margin-top: .5vh;
}
#contact-button:hover{
    color:  #FFF;
    background-color: #FF5733;
    border: solid .1rem #FF5733;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.masthead {
    height: 70vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#about{
    background-color: #FF5733;
    color: #FFF;
}
#overflow-container {
    width: auto;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #FF5733;
    overflow: visible;
    align-items: center;
}
#skills{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid .01rem #dedede;
    margin-left: auto 4rem;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;

}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel='icon' href='./img/cartoonme.png' type='image/x-icon' sizes="16x16" />
    <title>Rafael Arias</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/logo.svg" width="150" height="30" alt="RA"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#resume">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <button id="contact-button" class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</Button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <img src="./img/cartoonme.png" width="300" height="300"  alt="./img/ndisplay">
                <br>
                <h2>Welcome to my website!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="about" class="py-5">
        <div class="container py-5">
        <h2 class="text-center">About Me</h2>
        <p class="text-center">
            Hello, my name is Rafael Arias. I am extremely passionate about my career path in Front-End Development. I am naturally curious, and always seek to challenge and grow my professional character. 
            I love to learn coding languages. I never hesitate to dig into unfamiliar territory; I identify any task that may be difficult as a challenge.  I dedicate myself to advancing my professional well being and insuring functional results.
        </p>
        <p class="text-center">
            Below you can see the set of skills that I believe will apply to my position as a front end engineer!
        </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="overflow-container">
        <div id="skills" class="container py-5" >
            <h2 class="text-center">Skills</h2>
            <p class="text-center">Through many years of employment in different industries I have aquired many skills apart from the development skills I have aquired.</p>
            <br>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm text-center">
                <strong>Languages I Know</strong>
                <ul class="text-center">
                    <li>React.js</li>
                    <li>CSS3</li>
                    <li>HTML5</li>
                    <li>JavaScript</li>
                    <li>PHP</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm" class="align-items-center">
                <strong>Framework/Libraries I Know</strong>
                <div class="align-items-center">
                <ul class="text-center">
                    <li>Bootstrap</li>
                    <li>Redux</li>
                    <li>Bulma</li>
                    <li>Jquery</li>
                    <li>Styled Components</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                <strong>Tools I use for design and development</strong>
                <ul class="text-center">
                    <li>VS Code</li>
                    <li>Figma</li>
                    <li>Atom</li>
                    <li>Github</li>
                    <li>Hyper</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="py-5">
        <div class="container py-5">
            <h2>
                hello
            </h2>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am understand that it is because I placed the overflow to go there but I am wondering what the solution would be for thi situation. Would it be some sort of css that I forgot to input or would it happen to be with HTML.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How come you're choosing to work with an overflow approach to create this effect as opposed to going with a standard container that simply has position absolute?